# How to make certain text bold in MS Word

Tags: delphi, ms-word, delphi-xe5

I am using the following code to insert a table with 2 cells in MS Word using Delphi XE5. All the font for the table's cells are pretty straight forward. Except 1 word. I need this word to be bold while the rest is not.

Please help me adjust my code so i can make the 1 word bold.

```
wrdDoc.Tables.Add(wrdSelection.Range,3,2);
wrdDoc.tables.Item(3).Rows.Alignment := wdAlignRowLeft;

 wrdDoc.Tables.Item(3).Columns.Item(1).SetWidth(36,wdAdjustNone);
 wrdDoc.Tables.Item(3).Columns.Item(2).SetWidth(379,wdAdjustNone);
 wrdDoc.tables.Item(3).Borders.Item(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle := wdLineStyleNone;
 wrdDoc.tables.Item(3).Borders.Item(wdBorderRight).LineStyle := wdLineStyleNone;
 wrdDoc.tables.Item(3).Borders.Item(wdBorderVertical).LineStyle := wdLineStyleNone;
 wrdDoc.tables.Item(3).Borders.Item(wdBorderTop).LineStyle := wdLineStyleNone;
 wrdDoc.tables.Item(3).Borders.Item(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle := wdLineStyleNone;
 wrdDoc.tables.Item(3).Borders.Item(wdBorderHorizontal).LineStyle := wdLineStyleNone;

 wrdDoc.Tables.Item(3).Cell(1,1).Range.InsertAfter('8.1');
 wrdDoc.Tables.Item(3).Cell(1,1).Range.Paragraphs.Alignment := wdAlignParagraphleft;
 wrdDoc.Tables.Item(3).Cell(1,1).Range.Font.Size := 12;
 wrdDoc.Tables.Item(3).Cell(1,1).Range.Font.Bold := false;
 wrdDoc.Tables.Item(3).Cell(1,1).Range.Font.underline := false;

 wrdDoc.Tables.Item(3).Cell(1,2).Range.InsertAfter('this will not be bold text');
 wrdDoc.Tables.Item(3).Cell(1,2).Range.InsertAfter('this will not be bold text');
 wrdDoc.Tables.Item(3).Cell(1,2).Range.InsertAfter('THIS TEXT MUST BE BOLD');
 wrdDoc.Tables.Item(3).Cell(1,2).Range.Paragraphs.Alignment := wdAlignParagraphJustify;
 wrdDoc.Tables.Item(3).Cell(1,2).Range.Font.Size := 12;
 wrdDoc.Tables.Item(3).Cell(1,2).Range.Font.Bold := false;
 wrdDoc.Tables.Item(3).Cell(1,2).Range.Font.underline := false;
```

As you can see in the last part of the code, there is 3 calls for `InsertAfter()`, the sentences i am inserting are very long. and Delphi limits me to 255 so i just call them more than once and it is just as good as calling it once.

Only the last call, must be bold. The rest should just stay the format defined above.

Any and all help would be appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did manage to find a way. it is a bit messy but does the job.

```
Procedure MakeBold(SearchStr:String);
Begin
 WrdApp.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting;
     WrdApp.Selection.Find.Text := SearchStr;
     WrdApp.Selection.Find.Forward := True;
     WrdApp.Selection.Find.Wrap := wdFindContinue;
     WrdApp.Selection.Find.Format := False;
     WrdApp.Selection.Find.MatchCase :=  true;
     WrdApp.Selection.Find.MatchWholeWord := wrfMatchCase in Flags;
     WrdApp.Selection.Find.MatchWildcards :=wrfMatchWildcards in Flags;
     WrdApp.Selection.Find.MatchSoundsLike := False;
     WrdApp.Selection.Find.MatchAllWordForms := False;
     { Perform the search }
     WrdApp.Selection.Find.Execute();
  WrdApp.Selection.Font.Bold:=True;
End;
```

Then i just call `MakeBold('THIS TEXT MUST BE BOLD');` and it solves the problem.

Any other possible answers are still welcome, because this method may make other unrelated text also bold.

Answer (score 0):

You're working far too hard. :-) You need to become more familiar with Word Ranges (and the use of temporary variables). Tested using the Word2010 unit in Delphi 10 Seattle, using Word 2013.

```
var
  WordTbl: Table;

// Grab a local reference to the table for ease of use
Tbl := wrdDoc.Selection.Tables.Item(3);
Tbl.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text := 'not bold';

// Make sure the cell is the current selection
Tbl.Cell(1, 2).Select;

// Move the selection to the end of the text we wrote before
wrdDoc.Selection.EndKey(wdLine, wdMove);

// Add the next section of the text and move to the end, so we
// know for sure where Word thinks we are now. Notice the spaces
// at both ends - for some reason they make a difference
wrdDoc.Selection.Range.Text := ' BOLD TEXT ';
wrdDoc.Selection.EndKey(wdLine, wdMove);

// Move back two words to select the text we just added and bold
wrdDoc.Selection.MoveLeft(wdWord, 2, wdExtend);
wrdDoc.Selection.Font.Bold := 1;

// End of the line again, and turn bold off, then more text
wrdDoc.Selection.EndKey(wdLine, wdMove);
wrdDoc.Selection.Font.Bold := 0;
wrdDoc.Selection.Range.Text := 'not bold again';
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution makes all matches in the ActiveDocument are bold

```
function TfmMain.MakeBold(SearchStr: String; App: OLEVariant {Word application var} ): Integer;
var
  Find: OLEVariant;
begin
  Find := App.Selection.Find;
  Find.ClearFormatting;
  Find.Forward := true;
  Find.Wrap := wdFindStop;
  Find.Format := false;
  Find.MatchCase := false;
  Find.MatchWholeWord := true;
  Find.MatchWildcards := false;
  Find.MatchSoundsLike := false;
  Find.MatchAllWordForms := false;

  Find.Text := SearchStr;
  while Find.Execute() do
  begin
    App.Selection.Font.Bold := true;
    App.Selection.Collapse(wdCollapseEnd);
  end;
  Find := UnAssigned;
end;
```